# How to prove this linear application is unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider $T$ the linear application, $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by

$$T(1, 1, 1) = (-1, 2) \qquad  T(0, 1, 1) = (0, 4) \qquad T(1, 1, 0) = (2, 1)$$

How can I prove this $T$ is unique?

*Attempts*

The application $T$ is defined under a non canonical basis. (I proved the three vectors are a basis).

Now I wonder if this is sufficient to prove the uniqueness of $T$ and, if yes, why exactly it is.

Also I wanted to know what would happen if

- The three vector would not be a basis

I think there could be two cases now: the first one is if one of the three vectors is a multiple of the others, and the result is coherent. For example:

$$T(1, 1, 1) = (-1, 2) \qquad  T(2, 2, 2) = (-2, 4) \qquad T(1, 1, 0) = (2, 1)$$

and the second one is: incoherent result like

$$T(1, 1, 1) = (-1, 2) \qquad  T(2, 2, 2) = (-9, 0) \qquad T(1, 1, 0) = (2, 1)$$

In the second case I believe $T$ does not exist at all.

But what happens in the first case? Does $T$ still exist but not unique?

Thank you!

Comment: I assume this is $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$? As obvious as it might seem, I suggest making that explicit in the definition of $T$, and then using it in the proof.

Comment: @Stef Yes, Going to edit

Comment: A linear transform is completely defined by its values on a basis if the domain (canonical or otherwise) since any vector can be expressed uniquely as a liner combination of the elements of the basis.

Comment: @Mittens So if it's not a basis, then $T$ is not uniquely defined? I mean I just need to know if my "intuition" is correct about the last point in my question.

Comment: @Numb3rs: $(1,1,1)$, $(0,1,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$ do form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Mittens Ok, I know that. I said "the last point in my question", where I examine the case of a "non-basis".

Comment: @Numb3rs: any basis will do (canonical, orthogonal, or whatever other property a basis my have have). The point is that  for any vector in  the space has a *unique* representation as a liner combination of elements of a basis. Of course, one can change representation of a linear operators from one basis to another, which is a well known thing to do in linear algebra courses.

Comment: @Mittens I believe there is some communication problem... I said: what happens if the vectors ARE NOT A BASIS? Like in the examples I made at the end of my question. The vectors $(1, 1, 1)$, $(2, 2, 2)$ and $(1, 1, 0)$ are NOT a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. And I made two explicit examples: one in which the application should not exist and the other where... I don't know how to interpret it...

Comment: In your particular problem the vectors $(1,1,1)$, $(0,1,1)$, $(1,1,0)$ for a basis. If you don't have a basis, then you can only know how the linear operator acts on the subspace spanned by a given set of vectors, provided the values given for the vectors in the list are compatible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, $T$ is unique

If you have a basis for your vector space, then:

- Any vector can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in the basis;
- The definition of "an application is linear" is literally that the image of a linear combination is the linear combination of the images.

So, if you have a basis, and you know the image of the basis, then you can easily calculate the images of any vector.

If you like formulae more than words:
$$T(a e_1 + b e_2 + c e_3) = a T(e_1) + b T(e_2) + c T(e_3)$$

So that any vector $v$ can be written as a linear combination $v = a e_1 + b e_2 + c e_3$, and if you know the three images $T(e_1), T(e_2), T(e_3)$ then you know the image $T(v) = a T(e_1) + b T(e_2) + c T(e_3)$.

### Inconsistent definition of $T$ on a dependent family

There are two ways in which a family of vectors can be not a basis:

- It's a dependent family, ie it is possible to write 0 as a non-trivial linear combination of the vectors;
- It's not a generating family, ie there are vectors in the vector space that cannot be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors in the family

In case of a dependent family, if the images of $T$ are "inconsistent", then it is easy to prove that no ***linear*** application can reproduce the inconsistency.

With your example: If $T$ is a linear application, then we must have:
\begin{align*}
T(2(1,1,1)) & = 2 T(1,1,1) \\
T(2,2,2) & = 2 T(1,1,1) \\
\end{align*}
Hence there is no linear application such that $T(1,1,1) = (-1, 2)$ and $T(2,2,2) = (-9,0)$, since it's clear that $(-9,0) \neq 2(-1,2) = (-2,4)$.

Comment: What about the last point in my question?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. So I guess that in my example, in the coherent case, $T$ still does exist. Is it unique though? Or could I just ignore the action $T(2, 2, 2)$ (if it is coherent)? 
Is there an example of a non unique linear application?

Comment: @Numb3rs Yes, in case that the family is not generating, and the definitions are consistent, then there is typically an infinity of $T$ that work: first, remove redundant vectors from your family so that it's an independent family; then, you have anon-generating independent family, and this can be completed into a basis for the vector space (by adding independent vectors). Then, for the vectors that you have added, you can choose anything you want for the images by $T$, and every choice will give you a different unique choice of $T$.

Comment: BIG THANKS!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I would start with:

$$T(1, 1, 1) = (-1, 2) \qquad  T(0, 1, 1) = (0, 4) \qquad T(1, 1, 0) = (2, 1)$$

Now, what are $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ compared to $(1,1,1)$, $(0,1,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$?
You can easily see that:

$(1,0,0) = (1,1,1) - (0,1,1)$
$(0,1,0) = (0,1,1) + (1,1,0) - (1,1,1)$
$(0,0,1) = (1,1,1) - (1,1,0)$

Hence (applying $T$ on all of them):

$T(1,0,0) = (-1,2) - (0,4) = (-1,-2)$
$T(0,1,0) = (0,4) + (2,1) - (-1,2) = (3,3)$
$T(0,0,1) = (-1,2) - (2,1) = (-3,-3)$

Hence:
$T(a,b,c) = a \cdot T(1,0,0) + b \cdot T(0,1,0) + c \cdot T(0,0,1) = (-a+3b-3c,-2a+3b-3c)$